# Codeblocks project won't compile for the second time

Tags: c, codeblocks, glut

Okay, so I am working on opengl in codeblocks. My programs compile and run correctly when I build a project for the first time. But if I try to compile the program for the 2nd time it throws man errors like "undefined reference to '__imp__glutDisplayFunc@4'." and many similar errors.

I think it's some dll problem. I have the glut32.dll file in my system32 folder. What else could it be?

Comment: Try adding ```#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK ``` just before your include to ```glut.h ```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work.